# How can I undo the "Never ask me again" setting when I click the "New identity" button?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

When I click the "New Identity" button in Tor browser, there's a prompt

> Tor Browser will close all windows and tabs. All website sessions will be lost.
>
> Restart Tor Browser now to reset your identity?
>
> [ ] Never ask me again

I accidentally chose the "Never ask me again" and click [Yes].

Now I want to get the prompt back. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

#### Method 1: Use `about:config` page

- Type `about:config` into the navigation bar of Tor browser, accept the warning
- Search for `extensions.torbutton.confirm_newnym` option, change the value to `True`

#### Method 2: Modify the preference file in Tor browser directly

(**not recommended**! See the comment at the top of the file)

Open the file

```
tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default/prefs.js
```

There should be a line:

```
user_pref("extensions.torbutton.confirm_newnym", true);
```

Change `true` to `false`.

---

<sub>*I searched in Tor preferences window (and on the Internet) for a while and can't find anything related. Do post another answer if there's a simpler method.*</sub>